# How to create Linq Expression for DateTime.Date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to create Linq Expression for DateTime.Date?

For example:

```
var query = CollectionQuery.OrderBy(c => c.CreatedAtUtc.Date); // where CollectionQuery is User type
var expressions = query.Expression;
```

When I debug I found expressions contain expression type `Quote`:

[image]

I want it to be dynamic so I use `System.Linq.Expression` (EF Core 2.2)

```
ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "c");
var memberExpression = Expression.Property(arg, "CreatedAtUtc");
var quoteExpression = Expression.Quote(memberExpression); // no parameter to set .Date
```

My problem is I cannot create an expression with `.Date` - how can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: 1) you have to quote the whole `Expression.Lambda`, not just the body. 2) `Expression.Property(Expression.Property(arg, "CreatedAtUtc"), "Date")`

Comment: Do not put Answer into question. Just add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after @Jeremy Lakeman suggest

```
ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "c");
var memberExpression = Expression.Property(Expression.Property(arg, "CreatedAtUtc"), "Date"); // add this line
var labmdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, DateTime>>(memberExpression, arg);
var quoteExpression = Expression.Quote(labmdaExpression);
```

when I look into quoteExpression on debug it will show

[image]